# Insert values in every 4th row from a list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a URL list on the one hand and an empty list on an other hand. I want to fill the empty list with the URL list but only every 4th row.

For example the URL list:

- https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach/
- https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach/eins/
- https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach/zwei/

New (empty) list:

- A1: https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach/
- A2:
- A3:
- A4:
- A5: https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach/eins/
- A6:
- A7:
- A8:
- A9: https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach/zwei/

and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: do you need to be able to type/add anything in those empty cells?

Comment: yeah it would be nice if (for example) A1 also be insert in A2, A3 and A4

Comment: Are you able to share a sample sheet to check how you want the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.  Here is an answer that will not be clear enough either because there is not enough to go on.  But perhaps it will help you rephrase your question.  Try this in a cell:

```
=FLATTEN({A2:A10,A2:A10,A2:A10,A2:A10})
```